# SQL Server varchar inequalities - apostrophes yield strange results

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012

Behold the following query similar to one used in my company's code. The name column is of nvarchar(100) type:

```
select * 
from foo
where name >= 'papa d''s' 
    and name < 'papa d''szzzzzz'
```

This gives some unexpected results. In addition to returning any records where name = 'papa d's pizza inc', it also returns records where name = 'papa ds pizza inc'. Notice the missing apostrophe in the second result.

Now look at these two queries:

```
select 1 where 'papa ds pizza inc' >= 'papa d''s'
GO
select 1 where 'papa ds pizza inc' < 'papa d''szzzzzz'
```

Only the first query returns 1, implying that the AND condition in my first query should have failed.

Can someone tell me what's happening here?

Bonus points if you can describe why anyone would query this way as opposed to using a LIKE clause with a wildcard, assuming injection is thwarted with other validations.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't some other part of the `WHERE` clause causing unexpected rows to be returned? It might help if you post the complete query.

Comment: That is the complete query - I only changed the table/column names.
EDIT: For context, the name 'papa d''s' would normally be provided by a search field. C# appends the zzzzzz's for the query. But in my testing for this question I ran the query directly in SSMS as shown.

Comment: Not sure,but you might try using double quotes for the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with your `name` column being a double-byte string (`nvarchar`) and your string literals being single-byte strings (`char`/`varchar`). A SQL string literal like `'foobar'` is a single-byte string (`char`/`varchar`). To make it a double-byte string (`nchar`/`nvarchar`), you need to prefix it with `N`: `N'foobar'` is a double-byte string.

I think you've found a SQL Server bug. You can report it via Microsoft Connect at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer (but I wouldn't hold my breath on them fixing it).

I'm using a vanilla SQL Server 2012 installation with its default collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

- Executing this query using a single-byte (`varchar`) string:

  ```
  declare @name varchar(100) = 'papa ds pizza inc'
  select 'gt' where @name >= 'papa d''s'
  UNION
  select 'lt' where @name <  'papa d''szzzzzz'
  ```

  We get the expected result set:

  ```
  gt
  ```
- Changing the data type to double-byte (`nvarchar`),

  ```
  declare @name nvarchar(100) = N'papa ds pizza inc'
  select 'gt' where @name >= 'papa d''s'
  UNION
  select 'lt' where @name <  'papa d''szzzzzz'
  ```

  We get the unexpected result set

  ```
  gt
  lt
  ```
- And if we take the correctly working single-byte version and make the literals into double-byte literals:

  ```
  declare @name varchar(100) = 'papa ds pizza inc'
  select 'gt' where @name >= N'papa d''s'
  UNION
  select 'lt' where @name <  N'papa d''szzzzzz'
  ```

  We again get the incorrect and unexpected result set:

  ```
  gt
  lt
  ```